# Sphinx user is switching to Solr

Tags: solr, sphinx

I am Sphinx user since 3 years. The problem what I now become is clustering and facet support.

About the facet support, I know I can make it with sphinx as well and it will run, bu the clustering is one very big problem for me in the future.

I really like Sphinx, because it is easy to use and very fast, but I need to change to Solr in the next months.

I would like to to know some basics, if someone has bit time to explain me. I will post some examples in Sphinx and I hope you can give me the example in Solr.

As install I have choose Solr and Tomcat on Debian:

apt-get install solr-tomcat curl -y

Is this option with Tomcat better (faster, stable ...) then Jetty? Does both support clustering?

Second I have generated one Dataimport Handler with this :

```
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
              driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/database"
              user="root"
              password="root" 
      batchSize="-1"/>

<document name="doc">
    <entity name="de_job"
              query="select * from de_job">
        <field column="title" name="title" />
    <field column="description" name="description" />
    <field column="job_id" name="id" />
    </entity>
</document>
```

When I call:

http://domain.com:8080/solr/dataimport?command=full-import

then I have index over 1,6M data rows in 5 mins. This is great.

And here are my questions now:

1. I have in sphinx more then 1 index and want to reindex them in different times, not all at once.

   ```
   index de_jobs
   {
    source                  = de_jobs
    path                    = /usr/local/sphinx/var/data/jobs_de
    docinfo                 = extern
    charset_type            = utf-8
    charset_table           = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, \
                   U+430..U+44F,U+C5->U+E5, \
                   U+E5, U+C4->U+E4, U+E4, U+D6->U+F6, U+F6, U+16B, U+0c1->a, U+0c4->a, U+0c9->e, U+0cd->i, \
                   U+0d3->o, U+0d4->o, U+0da->u, U+0dd->y, U+0e1->a, U+0e4->a, U+0e9->e, U+0ed->i, U+0f3->o, \
                   U+0f4->o, U+0fa->u, U+0fd->y, U+104->U+105, U+105, U+106->U+107, U+10c->c, U+10d->c, \
                   U+10e->d, U+10f->d, U+116->U+117, U+117, U+118->U+119, U+11a->e, U+11b->e, U+12E->U+12F, \
                   U+12F, U+139->l, U+13a->l, U+13d->l, U+13e->l, U+141->U+142, U+142, U+143->U+144, \
                   U+144,U+147->n, U+148->n, U+154->r, U+155->r, U+158->r, U+159->r, U+15A->U+15B, U+15B, \
                   U+160->s, U+160->U+161, U+161->s, U+164->t, U+165->t, U+16A->U+16B, U+16B, U+16e->u, \
                   U+16f->u, U+172->U+173, U+173, U+179->U+17A, U+17A, U+17B->U+17C, U+17C, U+17d->z, \
                   U+17e->z, U+DC->U+FC, U+DF, U+FC,
   min_word_len            = 3
   min_infix_len           = 7
   stopwords               = /usr/local/sphinx/var/stopwords/stop_words_de.txt

   }

   index at_jobs
   {
    source                  = at_jobs
    path                    = /usr/local/sphinx/var/data/jobs_at
    docinfo                 = extern
    charset_type            = utf-8
    charset_table           = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, \
                   U+430..U+44F,U+C5->U+E5, \
                   U+E5, U+C4->U+E4, U+E4, U+D6->U+F6, U+F6, U+16B, U+0c1->a, U+0c4->a, U+0c9->e, U+0cd->i, \
                   U+0d3->o, U+0d4->o, U+0da->u, U+0dd->y, U+0e1->a, U+0e4->a, U+0e9->e, U+0ed->i, U+0f3->o, \
                   U+0f4->o, U+0fa->u, U+0fd->y, U+104->U+105, U+105, U+106->U+107, U+10c->c, U+10d->c, \
                   U+10e->d, U+10f->d, U+116->U+117, U+117, U+118->U+119, U+11a->e, U+11b->e, U+12E->U+12F, \
                   U+12F, U+139->l, U+13a->l, U+13d->l, U+13e->l, U+141->U+142, U+142, U+143->U+144, \
                   U+144,U+147->n, U+148->n, U+154->r, U+155->r, U+158->r, U+159->r, U+15A->U+15B, U+15B, \
                   U+160->s, U+160->U+161, U+161->s, U+164->t, U+165->t, U+16A->U+16B, U+16B, U+16e->u, \
                   U+16f->u, U+172->U+173, U+173, U+179->U+17A, U+17A, U+17B->U+17C, U+17C, U+17d->z, \
                   U+17e->z, U+DC->U+FC, U+DF, U+FC,
   min_word_len            = 3
   min_infix_len           = 7
   stopwords               = /usr/local/sphinx/var/stopwords/stop_words_de.txt

   }
   ```

How to enable in Solr 2 or more different indexes?

Are this different entities in the form below?

```
<entity name="de_job"
              query="select * from de_job">
        <field column="title" name="title" />
    <field column="description" name="description" />
    <field column="job_id" name="id" />
    </entity>

<entity name="at_job"
              query="select * from at_job">
        <field column="title" name="title" />
    <field column="description" name="description" />
    <field column="job_id" name="id" />
    </entity>
```

1. How can I reindex only the one index? Is there any parameter in the reindexing query:
   http://domain.com:8080/solr/dataimport?command=full-import where to select only de_job for example?
2. I have in Sphinx: min_word_len and min_infix_len . How to use this in Solr? Where can I configure it?
3. I have in Sphinx custom stopwords defined. How to define and use them in Solr for each index?
4. In sphinx I have to define charset_table because sphinx can not search for German Umlauts for example or other UTF-8 characters, if they are not translated by the charset_table. Do I need the same in Solr?
5. In index when I rotate an index, then sphinx is creating an tmp file, reindex the data and rotate it on the fly. In this way my application is running in the time, where sphinx is reindexing everything. How to solve this problem with Solr? When I look at the log file of Solr, when the index is rebuilding, then is staying:

REMOVING ALL DOCUMENTS FROM INDEX

What is bad, because in the time my app will not work. How can I solve this in elegant way?

Comment: If you mean clustering as in http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ClusteringComponent (I dont use Solr so dont know if it has something else too) - it appears to just using Carrot2. I use carrot2 along with sphinx just fine. Just like solr is seperate to Carrot2, sphinx can remain seperate too. Carrot2 has a "Document Clustering Server" which makes it very easy to start a instance of carrot2. Your application can then just call this - using the results from sphinx.

Comment: Here is a basic demo of a search run using sphinx, then clustered with Carrot2 http://nearby.org.uk/geograph/cluster-search.php?q=TQ5050

Answer (score 0):

1. Create separate cores for each index. Then each one will have its own dataimport URL.
2. (a) min_word_len, ignore this, not needed. (b) min_infix_len, can be ignored for now unless you do a lt of wildcard queries. If you do, then consider using Ngrams.
3. In your schema, define a stopword filter and put your stopwords in a file. Even better, don't use stopwords. Those are a bad habit left over from 32-bit computers and 40 Megabyte disks.
4. You can use ISOLatin1AccentFilterFactory in your schema (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters/#solr.ISOLatin1AccentFilterFactory).
5. This is normal, the delete won't actually happen until the indexing completes and the new content is committed.

Comment: Hi Walter, thanks for the fast answer. I have 2 questions now: To point 1: How to define, to which core is the index? DO you have some example for me? To point 5: Means, that it works like sphinx? It will display the old information during the reindex?

Comment: Solr cores are independent search configurations inside one Solr server. More info here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin Yes, searches continue uninterrupted during indexing.